# VSTS - Custom Build on Powershell and upload to Artifact to directory

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

did anyone have worked custom build on the powershell and upload the artifact to the VSTS directory.

I have configured Build Process on the VSTS agent, Build process all passed and i have artifact, we also need to encrypt the app, the process is on CLI, i have powershell script execute those tasks, but i couldn't able to upload that articats to VSTS directory,

his anyone have any idea how can i achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks (i) button helps understand the directory you'll be working in the context of for a task.

[image: Powershell Task]

In the instance of the Powershell task it will be working from the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). If the powershell task is in version control use the ... button to select the powershell script you wish to execute.

Once your script executes you'll probably want a Copy Task to copy the file you just encrypted to $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) something like this (obviously you'll need to modify the contents field so it copies the encrypted file from the powershell step):

[image: Copy Task]

Then you're ready to publish to Azure DevOps taking the contents of  $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) and making this an artifact for the build. In the below example this artifact will be called drop.

[image: Publish]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeaaa. bro the process was needed in the Release pipeline, that was didn't work even after multiple tries and different methods, so I used the same method in the build, it works... because they have the option to copy the artifact.